# We need to add a counter, in which, after clicking on the Badge button, it displays the number of items in the cart

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks

We need to add a counter, in which, after clicking on the Badge button, it displays the number of items in the cart. Tell me how to pass it through the class component. I have a Navbar class component, it has a Badge that should show how many products have been added to the cart, and there is a Cart class that needs to be passed to Navbar as props. Tell me how to pass it through the class component.

```
<Badge count={this.state.totalItems}>
  <ShoppingCartOutlined />
  </Badge>
```

here I feed yogo through the constructor

```
class Navbar extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      current: "mail",
      }
    }

  handleClick = (e) => {
    console.log("click ", e);
    this.setState({ current: e.key });
  };

  render() {
    
    const { t } = this.props;
    const { current } = this.state;
    return (
      
      <div className="navbar">
        <Menu
          onClick={this.handleClick}
          selectedKeys={[current]}
          mode="horizontal"
        >
          <Menu.Item key="main" icon={<HomeOutlined />}>
            {t("menu.home")}
          </Menu.Item>
          <Menu.Item key="favorites" icon={<HeartOutlined />}>
            {t("menu.favorites")}
          </Menu.Item>
          <Menu.Item key="Faq" icon={<QuestionCircleOutlined />}>
            {t("menu.faq")}
          </Menu.Item>
        </Menu>

        <div className="navbar__logo">
          CLOTHES
          <span>.STORE</span>
        </div>
        <Menu
          onClick={this.handleClick}
          selectedKeys={[current]}
          mode="horizontal"
          className="right-menu"
        ></Menu>
        <div className="button_sign">{t("menu.signup")}</div>
        <Badge count={this.state.totalItems}>
          <ShoppingCartOutlined />
        </Badge>
        <div className="navbar_lang">
          <SetLanguage />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export const Cart = ({ totalItems}) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <>
      <AppBar position="fixed" className={classes.appBar} color="inherit">
          <div>
              <IconButton arial-label="Show cart items" color="inherit">
                <Badge badgeContent={totalItems} color="secondary">
                    <ShoppingCart/>
                </Badge>
              </IconButton>
          </div>
      </AppBar>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the value of `totalItems` in the state of a Parent Component from a Child Component, you can:

- Use a state management tool (ex: redux) if your application will grow bigger
- If it's a simple case like yours here, you can create a method inside the **parent component** called `increment`, pass it as **props** to the **child component** and call it there. It will be bound and executed in the context of the Parent Component.

```
class Navbar extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      current: "mail",
      totalItems: 0, // add the total to the state
      }
    }

  // Define increment inside the parent component 
  increment = () => {
    this.setState({totalItems: totalItems++})
  }

  render() {
    
    const { t } = this.props;
    const { current } = this.state;
    return (
      
      // ...

        <Badge count={this.state.totalItems}>
          <ShoppingCartOutlined count={this.state.totalItems} increment={this.increment} />
        </Badge>
      
      // ...
    );
  }
}
```

Then, inside your child component, call that method with a click listener:

```
export const ShoppingCartOutlined = ({ count, increment }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <>
      <AppBar position="fixed" className={classes.appBar} color="inherit">
          <div>
              <IconButton arial-label="Show cart items" color="inherit">
                <Badge
                  badgeContent={count}
                  onClick={increment} // or () => increment()
                  color="secondary"
                >
                    <ShoppingCart/>
                </Badge>
              </IconButton>
          </div>
      </AppBar>
    </>
  );
};
```